# Ошибка связанная с функциями

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Код:

```
import os
def cl():
    os.system("cls")
print("")
print('''Здравствуйте, это игра "Легенда о Сабине"!
Ваша задача побеждать монстров и спасти принцессу Сабину!
Она в заключении у злого мага Гаргамеля!
Удачи воин!
================================================================================''')
name=input("Ведите имя вашего героя: ")
if name.lower()=="netexplorer" or name.lower()=="нетексплорер":
    money=100000
elif name.lower()=="говно" or name.lower()=="гавно":
    money=-1000
    print("'_'")
    debil=input("")
else:
    money=50
hp=100
resh='Меню'

armor=2
level_armor=0
level_armor2=level_armor+1
price_armor=50

damage=1
level_damage=0
level_damage2=level_damage+1

day=1
def stat():
    cl()
    print('-------------------------', resh ,'---- ',name, '-- день ',day,'------------------------')
    print('-Здоровье ', hp)
    print('-Броня',armor,'%', level_armor,'ур')
    print('-Урон',damage,level_damage,'ур')
    print('-Деньги',money)
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
def mag():
    global level_armor2,armor,price_armor,damage,money,resh,level_armor,level_damage, level_damage2,price_damage
    cl()
    stat()
    print('''-----------------------------------------------
Броня''',level_armor2,'ур',price_armor,'''монет
Оружие''',level_damage2,'ур',price_damage,'''монет
Назад
-----------------------------------------''')
    resh=input("Напишите раздел: ")
    if resh.lower()=="назад":
        resh="Меню"
        cl()
        stat()
        menu()
    elif resh.lower()=="оружие":
        cl()
        stat()
        if money>=price_damage:
            level_damage=level_damage+1
            level_damage2=level_damage+1
            print('''Прокачка успешно завершена!
Теперь твоя броня''',level_damage, "уровня")
            money=money-price_damage
            price_damage=price_damage*2
            if level_damage<=3:
                damage=damage*2
            else:
                for y in range(0,20):
                    damage=damage+5+y
            back=input("Пиши назад: ")
            if back.lower()=="назад":
                resh="Магазин"
                mag()
            else:
                print("grrrrrrrr...")
                resh="Меню"
                menu()
        else:
            print("Недостаточно денег..")
            bomj=input("")
            resh="Магазин"
            mag()
    elif resh.lower()=="зелья":
        cl()
        stat()
        resh=input('''Недоделал))
Назад''')
        if resh.lower()=="назад":
            resh="Магазин"
            cl()
            stat()
            mag()
    elif resh.lower()=="броня":
        cl()
        stat()
        if money>=price_armor:
            level_armor=level_armor+1
            level_armor2=level_armor+1
            print('''Прокачка успешно завершена!
Теперь твоя броня''',level_armor, "уровня")
            money=money-price_armor
            price_armor=price_armor*2
            if level_armor<=3:
                armor=armor*2
            else:
                for i in range(0,20):
                    armor=armor+5+i
            back=input("Пиши назад: ")
            if back.lower()=="назад":
                resh="Магазин"
                mag()
            else:
                print("grrrrrrrr...")
                resh="Меню"
                menu()
        else:
            print("Недостаточно денег..")
            bomj=input("")
            resh="Магазин"
            mag()
    else:
        print("Я не понимаю...")
        bomj=input("")
        resh="Магазин"
        mag()
def menu():
    cl()
    global level_armor,money,armor,price_armor,resh,damage,level_damage,level_damage2,day,hp,damage
    stat()
    print('''Ваши действия (Напишите нужное действие):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Магазин
Карта
Дом
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------''')
    resh=input("Напишите действие: ")
    if resh.lower()=="магазин":
        mag()
    elif resh.lower()=="карта":
        cl()
        stat()
        back=input('''Недоделал))
Назад ''')
        if back.lower()=="назад":
            cl()
            stat()
            menu()
        else:
            menu()
    elif resh.lower()=="дом":
        cl()
        stat()
        back=input('''Недоделал))
Назад ''')
        if back.lower()=="назад":
            cl()
            stat()
            menu()
        else:
            menu()
    else:
        cl()
        print("")
        print("")
        print("---------------------------------Не понимаю!----------------------------------")
        print("")
        print("")
        nepoinimau=input(":) ")
        resh="Меню"
        menu()
menu()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Игра-Сабина\sabina-0.3.0.py", line 171, in <module>
    menu()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Игра-Сабина\sabina-0.3.0.py", line 138, in menu
    mag()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Игра-Сабина\sabina-0.3.0.py", line 46, in mag
    Оружие''',level_damage2,'ур',price_damage,'''монет
NameError: name 'price_damage' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: Я не могу понять в чём ошибка, уже запутался.

Comment: Причина та же, что и в прошлом вашем вопросе - непонимание областей видимости.

Comment: Ок, я проверю, благодарю

Comment: Прошу прощения но не нашёл ошибку прошу помощи...

Comment: `global price_damage` этого не достаточно для объявления переменной, попробуйте в функцию mag() после строки `global ...` добавить строку `price_damage = None`

Comment: Благодарю, напишите ответом! Дабы получит репутацию, я сделаю это принятым ответом.